# which neo4j library for .NET to pick?

Tags: .net, neo4j

I'm looking for neo4j .NET library. I have tried out many but still haven't found any with good documentation and examples.

Most of all I would like to use Cypher query language.

Could anyone recommend a good library which includes the documentation or at least clear cypher examples?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,
both clients at http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/tutorials-rest.html have experimental Cypher support, maybe you can ping the authors and contribute? Would be much appreciated!